# Simple JPA Named Query and EntityManager return nothing

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish

I have JPA Entity class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "actor")
@Entity
@Table
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Actor.getByName", query = "SELECT v FROM Actor v WHERE v.name = :name"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Actor.getAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Actor e")})
public class Actor implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      @Column
      private int id;
      @Column
      private String name;
      @Column
      private String birthDate;
      @Column
      private String email;
      @Column
      private String image;

      //getters and setters here
      //no argument constructor and all arguments constructor
}
```

DAO Local:

```
@Local
public interface ActorDaoLocal {
    Actor getActor(int actorId);
    public List<Actor> getAllActors();
}
```

And DAO:

```
@Stateless
public class ActorDao implements ActorDaoLocal {
   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em ;

   @Override
   public Actor getActor(int actorId) {
       return em.find(Actor.class, actorId);
   }

   @Override
   public List<Actor> getAllActors() {
      Query named = em.createNamedQuery("Actor.getAll", Actor.class);
      return named.getResultList();
}
```

In MainController I am invoking these methods:

```
@Path("/actors")
public class MainController {

   @EJB
   private ActorDaoLocal actorDao;

   @GET
   @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
   public List<Actor> getAllActors() {
      System.out.println("Getting all actors...");
      List<Actor> actorList = actorDao.getAllActors();
      Actor actor = actorDao.getActor(1);
      System.out.println("actor "  + actor); //this is null
      return actorList; //this is empty list
}
```

My problem is that Dao methods are returning null for `getActor` method and empty list for `getAllActors` method. 
I am working at GlassFish. Connection with database seems to be okay, in Glassfish console I don't see any exceptions. And, of course, I have some rows i DB.

edit: persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="ZajacPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/actordb"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="app"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="app"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```

Comment: Try to post full MainController

Comment: I've edited my question post

Comment: try to post the Persistence.xml

Comment: Done, I've edited my question post

Comment: and the SQL issued by the query is ? You have debugged it haven't you?!

Comment: Local derby databases are usually started up on the fly, so how are you verifying you have rows in the database table being queried?  Have you tried persisting an entity and then reading it back?